# Why does the delete method not free up memory for a widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, memory-leaks, widget

In Tkinter I have a large block of code that updates and clears a ScrolledText widget. I noticed during testing however that there was a memory leak regarding this, and after narrowing it down the simplest way to replicate this behavior is:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext
def meme(box_text):
    while True:
        box_text.insert("end", "meme")
        box_text.delete(1.0, "end")
window_main = tkinter.Tk()
box_text = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window_main)
button = tkinter.Button(window_main, command=lambda: meme(box_text))
box_text.pack()
button.pack()
window_main.mainloop()
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? I don't understand nor see the problem with this in relation to memory. If I comment out the insert, with only the delete, there's no memory issue so the loop itself is not to blame as far as I can tell, only the insert.

Comment: Why do you call this s a memory leak? Are you seeing memory go up forever? What tool are you using to determine this? How much memory is leaking per loop iteration?

Comment: I'm just using windows task manager. And yes, depending on the loops of insert / delete the memory seems to rise unbounded.

Comment: It's probably at least partly related to the fact that you never let the event loop process events, so events keep queing up without the queue being drained. Since you would never use code like this in the real world, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: If I change the `while True` to `for x in range(100):`, allowing for it to return it still does not release the memory, which is similar to my actual code. Problem here is I am using a loop that has insert and delete, (not infinite, nor repeated that often) and this problem exists. Even though the memory is expanding slightly over time it's still worrying.

Comment: Python won't release the memory to the os, but it can be reused by the program while it has s running. If you have a true memory leak, I honestly don't thnk it is related to repeated inserts and deletes.

Comment: Ah, I see. I hope that is that case then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit. For the Text widget by default "maxundo" is set to 0, and thus Tkinter keeps a log of everything inserted into it. Setting this to 1 solved the problem. Edit: `undo=False` works better.